# Is it more common to write "wakarimasu" with or without kanji?

Tags: word-choice, kanji-choice

I've had two vocabulary lists where *wakarimasu* is written as 分かります. However most of the time in news articles and manga I find it back as just わかります. So I wondered what is commonly used among Japanese people.

Is it like writing *ohayou* as お早う or is it just a matter of preference?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are the hit counts from [BCCWJ](http://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/en/).

All entries (1971-2008):

- わかった: 6492　分かった: 1739　解った: 130
- わかります: 2834　分かります: 1065　解ります: 109
- おはよう: 1300　お早う: 84
- ありがとう: 7090　有難う: 420　有り難う: 102

Recent entries (2000-):

- わかった: 4162　分かった: 1327　解った: 92
- わかります: 2164　分かります: 989　解ります: 100
- おはよう: 1140　お早う: 47
- ありがとう: 5573　有難う: 332　有り難う: 95

(Note: these should contain a few false-positives such as こわかった and 随分かったるい)

So わかる is roughly 3 times more common than 分かる, but 分かる is not uncommon at all. While お早う is becoming less and less popular, the usage of 分かる is not declining.

I personally think both わかる and 分かる are totally fine unless you are a professional writer who has to follow some opinionated guideline. I recommend you write おはよう and ありがとう in hiragana.

Comment: A parsed version of BCCWJ is available at http://nlb.ninjal.ac.jp/search/. In an [entry](http://nlb.ninjal.ac.jp/headword/V.00015/) click on the tab `基本` and then expand `書字形`. This way you can avoid (most) false positives.

Comment: @Earthliŋ Thank you, this site seems really useful.

Answer (score 10):

Indeed, わかる is mostly written in *kana*.

[Corpus data](http://nlb.ninjal.ac.jp/headword/V.00015/) gives the following proportions:

```
わかる    58280    71%
分かる    17700    22%
解る       2964     4%
判る       2580     3%
```

A priori there seems to be no reason not to use the *kanji* as わ・かる is a *jōyō* reading of 分 (taught already in the second year of primary school).

Indeed, [this publisher](http://www.mitsumura-tosho.co.jp/webmaga/kotoba/detail17.html) explains that for their *primary school* books, they use 分かる applying the principle "use *kanji* you have learned wherever you can". However, their secondary school books use わかる whenever the intended meaning is "to understand/realize", since in this sense 解る or 判る might be more suited, but these readings are not official *jōyō* readings. They explain that many dictionaries associate 分かる to 「はっきりしていなかったことに区別がつく」 — an English equivalent might be "to differentiate" — which is close in meaning to other readings of 分 such as 分ける "to divide".

(Of course, the meaning of "understand" derives from "differentiate" and you are free to choose to write both in *kanji* as 分かる without raising too many eyebrows. The above just gives some numbers/reasons showing that and explaining why わかる might be chosen over 分かる.)